# manipulating data table joining in scala data frame

Tags: scala, dataframe

Given two data frames in scala, T1, T2, I wanna only keep values in T1 where IDs exist in T2, but values don't exist in T2. For instance

T1

```
+---+---+
| ID|val| 
+---+---+
|  1|  x|
|  1|  y|
|  1|  z|
|  2|  x|
|  2|  y|
|  3|  x|
|  3|  y|
|  3|  z|
|  3|  k|
|  4|  x|
|  4|  y|
|  4|  z|
|  5|  x|
+---+---+
```

T2

```
+---+---+
| ID|val| 
+---+---+
|  1|  x|
|  1|  y|
|  2|  x|
|  3|  x|
|  3|  y|
|  4|  x|
|  4|  y|
|  4|  z|
|  5|  x|
+---+---+
```

For ID=1, values x, y exist in T2, and for ID=2, values x exists in T2, and for ID=3, values x, y exist in T2, and for ID=4, values x, y, z exist in T2, and for ID=5, value x exists in T3, so excluding those values, we get

```
+---+---+
| ID|val| 
+---+---+
|  1|  z|
|  2|  y|
|  3|  z|
|  3|  k|
+---+---+
```

as answer.

I'm trying something like

```
T1.join(T2, Seq("ID", "val")).filter(T1.col("ID")===T2.col("ID") && T1.col("val")===T2.col("val"))
```

but not sure if this is correct/efficient approach or not.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I'm kinda new to scala.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several ways to achive this operation.

This operation is the difference between df1 and df2, you could try the following approach with dataframe API:

```scala
val result2 = df1.except(df2)
result2.show()
```

```scala
+---+---+
| ID|val|
+---+---+
|  1|  z|
|  3|  z|
|  2|  y|
|  3|  k|
+---+---+
```

Another approach with the Dataframe API would be with `anti-join`

```scala
val joinCondition = col("ID") === col("ID1") and col("val") === col("val1")
val result3 = df1.join(df2, joinCondition, "left_anti")
result3.show()
```

```scala
+---+---+
| ID|val|
+---+---+
|  1|  z|
|  3|  z|
|  2|  y|
|  3|  k|
+---+---+
```

And finally this approach would be transform dataframes to a set to calculate the difference between the two sets

```scala
val setting = (df1.collect().toSet -- df2.collect().toSet).toList
val result = sc
    .parallelize(setting.map(r => (r(0).toString.toInt,r(1).toString)))
    .toDF("ID","val")
    result.show()
```

```scala
+---+---+
| ID|val|
+---+---+
|  2|  y|
|  3|  z|
|  3|  k|
|  1|  z|
+---+---+
```